# How can I put these array images into separate divs?

Tags: php, image, html

This PHP code generates three pictures, with three quotes. I've been struggling for the past few days, so how can I make it generate each image and text into a new div tag?
This is the code:

```
<div id="randown" style="width: 475px; left: 10px; top:  15px; height: 89px;"class="style4">
<?php
define('RANDOM_IMAGES_COUNT2',3);
define('RANDOM_IMAGES_FORMAT2', '<img src="%s" style="width:177px;height:100px;border-   style:solid;border-width:2px;border-color:black;" /><a href="%s" alt="%s" title2="%s">%s</a>');

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

$images = array (
    array ( 'title2' => 'Test 2', 'src2' => 'pic2.jpg', 'href2' => 'http://mylink.com/path/','text2' => 'Hello' ),
    array ( 'title2' => 'Test 2', 'src2' => 'pic7.jpg', 'href2' => 'http://mylink.com/path/','text2' => 'Hello2' ),
    array ( 'title2' => 'Test 2', 'src2' => 'pic9.jpg', 'href2' => 'http://mylink.com/path/','text2' => 'Hello2' ), 
    array ( 'title2' => 'Test 2', 'src2' => 'pic5.jpg', 'href2' => 'http://mylink.com/path/','text2' => 'Hello2' ),     
    array ( 'title2' => 'Test 2', 'src2' => 'pic3.jpg', 'href2' => 'http://mylink.com/path/','text2' => 'Hello3' )
);

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if ( count($images) < RANDOM_IMAGES_COUNT2 ) {
    trigger_error('Not enough images given', E_USER_WARNING);
    exit;
}

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

for ($i = 0; $i < RANDOM_IMAGES_COUNT2; $i++) {
    shuffle($images);

    $tmp = array_shift($images);
    printf( RANDOM_IMAGES_FORMAT2, $tmp['src2'], $tmp['href2'], $tmp['title2'],     $tmp['title2'],$tmp['text2'] );    }
?>
</div>
```

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the surrounding div tags in the constant definition:

```
define('RANDOM_IMAGES_FORMAT2', '<div><img src="%s" style="width:177px;height:100px;border-   style:solid;border-width:2px;border-color:black;" /><a href="%s" alt="%s" title2="%s">%s</a></div>');
```

Comment: Is there any way I can add styles to this div tag?

Comment: Sure. Add a class or use inline css.

Comment: Don't I have to declare the div tags in the array also?

Comment: No, because sprintf uses the contents of the constant `RANDOM_IMAGES_FORMAT2` as template.

Comment: You've helped me solve one problem, but now theres another one. The images are under each other, and I want them side by side. They dont have unique id's so I dont know how i can rearrange them??

Comment: add a float to the divs. If you have any more problem with that create a new question with the markup you have as a result and describe what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[Working codepad example](http://codepad.org/bXLd24I5)

Note that I replaced your href and the names of the jpeg images in order to test/solve on my system. Easy enough to change back, I trust.

```
<?php
    $images = array (
        array ( 'title1' => 'Test 2', 'src2' => '50x50', 'href2' => 'http://placehold.it/','text2' => 'Hello1' ),
        array ( 'title2' => 'Test 2', 'src2' => '75x75', 'href2' => 'http://placehold.it/','text2' => 'Hello2' ),
        array ( 'title3' => 'Test 2', 'src2' => '100x100', 'href2' => 'http://placehold.it/','text2' => 'Hello3' ), 
        array ( 'title4' => 'Test 2', 'src2' => '150x150', 'href2' => 'http://placehold.it/','text2' => 'Hello4' ),     
        array ( 'title5' => 'Test 2', 'src2' => '200x200', 'href2' => 'http://placehold.it/','text2' => 'Hello5' )
    );

    $cnt = count($images);


    $r = '';
    for ($i=0; $i<=$cnt; $i++) {
        $r .= '<div id="imgDiv-' .$i. '" style="padding:10px;">';
        $r .= '<img id="img-' .$i. '" src="';
        $r .= $images[$i]['href2'] . $images[$i]['src2'];
        $r .= '" />';
        $r .= '</div>';
    }

?>

<html>

    <body>

        Here is the PHP: <br>
        <?php echo $r; ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can also [test it here](http://writecodeonline.com/php/) (just delete top opening php tag `<?php` and insert an opening php tag at very bottom).

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use the existing code he has? It is quite simple adding a div there.

Comment: @KaRoLis  No, as code constructs the `$r` variable, it is adding the `<div>` tags. It also assigns each div an id, such as `id=imgDiv-3`. Do you see it?